# PHP 5.2.13 doesn't work on Windows 7 on apache 2.2

Tags: php, windows-7, apache-2.2

I have a test server on a Windows 7 Machine with apache 2.2 installed. On it PHP 5.2.11 was workig fine (as a module). But when I try to install 5.2.13 (or greater). It doesn't start.

Nothing beside the PHP version is different. I unzip the files and add the lines.

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "c:/PHP"
```

But that LoadModule directive doesn't let apache start. When I comment that line apache starts. When I replace the files with those in 5.2.11 package Everything works fine again.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: i dont know why this happened but with this post you save me after 4 hour losing my head over why this didnt work! i just used the 5.2.11 and everything works well now!!! thanks a lot really!

Answer (score 1):

- Try to check the Windows event log and any other configured log files for Apache and PHP.
- Try 5.2.12 to see what that gives. Why is 5.2.13 needed? Why not go to 5.3.*?
- Try another version of Apache.
- Try reinstalling both Apache and PHP.
- Try to use IIS 7 instead of Apache as a last resort.
- Try an all-in-one package like XAMPP that will do the hard stuff for you.